# Handle errors in visualforce table with multiple checkbox

Tags: visualforce, dmlexception, datatable.js

In the visualforce page, we are binding list of records and the table has Select All checkbox. When selected the records in the page get selected and there we placed a option to open a modal popup to change the date. Now my problem is if they select around 4 to 5 records and lets say 2 records fails in the update due to the validation rules in the backend, how to handle this scenario efficiently to show the error message?

Comment: how are these being passed in for updating? Remoting? Have you any code you can display to show first what you've done - or tried?

Comment: Yes it is done using javascript remoting. I believe we can use Database.saveresult and the failed record and show the result in the alert string.. Is that the right approach?

Comment: that would work - are you intending to apply the error to the row that you updated? i would suggest when you return your records - if you're remoting and you want to show the error on the row - Assuming that these rows are in a wrapper ( given you're using a list with checkboxes ) - add to your wrapper an error Message String field and a Boolean field to mark that an error exists - you can then show the error string on the row. i will submit as an answer what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as i was saying your remoting call can return your error message on the row by simply displaying an error string and a render the error string on the row by a boolean property in your wrapper.

Wrapper:

```
public class MyObjectWrapper {
    public Boolean hasErrors { get; set; }
    public String errorMessage { get; set; }
    public Boolean selected { get; set; }

    // use this to fetch your item to check the error list
    public Id wrapperRecordId { get; set; } 
    .... 
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listWrappers}" var="item" >
    <apex:column>
       <apex:facet name="header"><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectAll}" /></apex:facet>
       <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!item.selected}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
      ....
    </apex:column>
    .....

    <apex:column rendered="{!item.hasErrors}" >
       <apex:facet name="header">Error</apex:facet>
       <apex:outputText value="{!item.errorMessage}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

And using the Database.SaveResult[] in your remoting method - you can mark the error records with the error cause and has errors - rerender your table